# Postgresql create view for child displaing parents

Tags: postgresql, view, many-to-many

all about Postgres, I have three table: children, parent, children_to_parent.
It is many to many relationship.

children_tab:
children_id | name | lastname

parent_tab:
parent_id | name | lastname

children_to_parent
children_id | parent_id

Every children has got one or two parents.

I would like to create children view that also will contain 4 additional columns: parent_id_1, parent_fullname_1, parent_id_2, parent_fullname_2.

I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this model, you would have to guarantee that rules will be applied correctly, because otherwise many problems could occur:

1. One child can have more than 2 parents
2. One child can have no parents

But assuming that this will be restricted by your application, you can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) and enter in *child_to_parent* table some times to handle this:

```
select  ch.children_id, 
    ch.name, 
    ch.lastname, 
    pt1.parent_id parent_id_1, 
    pt1.name parent_name_1, 
    pt1.lastname parent_lastname_1, 
    pt2.parent_id parent_id_2, 
    pt2.name parent_name_2, 
    pt2.lastname parent_lastname_2
from    children_tab ch
    -- JOIN for parent 1
    left join (
        select  ch.children_id, ch.parent_id
            ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ch.children_id ORDER BY ch.parent_id asc) rown
        from    children_to_parent ch
    ) window_prt1 on ch.children_id=window_prt1.children_id and window_prt1.rown=1
    left join parent_tab pt1 on window_prt1.parent_id=pt1.parent_id
    -- JOIN for parent 2
    left join (
        select  ch.children_id, ch.parent_id
            ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ch.children_id ORDER BY ch.parent_id asc) rown
        from    children_to_parent ch
    ) window_prt2 on ch.children_id=window_prt2.children_id and window_prt2.rown=2
    left join parent_tab pt2 on window_prt2.parent_id=pt2.parent_id
```

Your result will look like this:

[image]

Note that I used `LEFT JOIN` because your children, based on this database model, can have no parent. So its data will return with parents data as null.

You should consider not using this *children_to_parent* table and put these IDs in children_tab (ex: parent1_id, parent2_id) and create a FK to parent_tab based on these columns.

Using this model you can force *not null* to them and know who is father and who is the mother (ex: father_id and mather_id) linking them to parent_tab table (to parent_id column).